# FAST search for specific managed metadata term with child terms

Tags: sharepoint, search

Im trying to form a query from SharePoint that searches for a specific managed metadata term, including any child terms.
I found this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff625182 that helped me a bit,
after testing this out i was able to query for my term by using the owsTaxIdMetadataAllTagsInfo in my querystring with the GUID of the term i am searching for.

However, this only works if I use the leading 0, i.e. to search for a specific term ONLY without child terms.

if i omit the leading 0, to seach for child terms of the term with the GUID i provide in the query string i get no results???

e.g.

`http://myFASTsearch/Pages/advsearch-results.aspx?k=owstaxidmetadataalltagsinfo:01a2acafe-0306-490d-8aa4-80a7bc0b4a13`  this gives me results

`http://myFASTsearch/Pages/advsearch-results.aspx?k=owstaxidmetadataalltagsinfo:1a2acafe-0306-490d-8aa4-80a7bc0b4a13`   this gives me NO results.

what am i missing

Thanks,

Craig.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the page you provided, should you use r parameter?

`http://contoso/searchcenter/pages/results.aspx?k=turtle&r=owstaxIdMetadataAllTagsInfo=#52263385-1fc3-4323-8d6b-50c8f6c3c45d:"reference materials"`

As that article might have errors, also try this (note " around r parameter):

`http://contoso/searchcenter/pages/results.aspx?k=turtle&r="owstaxIdMetadataAllTagsInfo"=#52263385-1fc3-4323-8d6b-50c8f6c3c45d:"reference materials"`

Comment: Theat doesnt work either, if I put the # in, either with the leading 0 or without, i get no results at all.

Answer (score 0):

owstaxIdMetadataAllTagsInfo is not supported for use with child items. You have to use the owstaxIdYourMMColumn:"column value"

Where YourMMColumn is the column name you have used in a list or library.
Blog about it here http://www.spsdemo.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=378